# Why does the syslog timestamp not include a year?

Tags: date, syslog

I am planning to store some of my log messages for more than a year, but the syslog timestamp description from [RFC3164](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3164.txt) does not include a year in the timestamp portion of a log entry. An example timestamp that I found in my CentOS log messages is `Mar 16 07:46:24`.

[RFC5424](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5424#section-6.2.3) is supposed to make RFC3164 obsolete, but it seems very common across operating systems to use a `mmm dd` date in logs. RFC5424 is six years old, so I am surprised it is not standard. Why wasn't a year included in RFC3164? Are logs meant to be very temporary? What is the reason for not including a year in logs today?

Comment: From a practical point of view, if you rotate logfiles, additional information is available from the filename or file metadata of the rotated file.

Comment: will the log file's creation date not help?

Comment: I suspect "compatibility with 35 years' worth of BSD-style syslog logs" is the reason, but have no documented proof. When you eventually switch to `systemd` (resistance is futile), you can use `journalctl`'s `-o short-iso` option to get real ISO 8601 timestamps.

Comment: @MilindDumbare alas, the log file's creation date is not reliable. Log files may be copied prior to analysis. Also, syslog allows messages to be moved from machine-to-machine, so the creation date on the machine where the syslog messages are collected may have nothing to do with where they were sent. They may even be collected in a database, and not in a file.

Comment: Anyone looking for a reference can certainly use @MarkPlotnick as a reference. He's been around a while, too...  See: https://books.google.com/books?id=qSErMDyLDosC&pg=PA27&lpg=PA27&dq=Mark+Plotnick+bell+labs&source=bl&ots=l91lPvbe01&sig=bkSfZ0qXvo7XnNEmNgmKh9P415E&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwixnp6EsK_fAhWi5lQKHQ6JACEQ6AEwBHoECF8QAQ#v=onepage&q=Mark%20Plotnick%20bell%20labs&f=false

Answer (score 5):

If you *would* like to add custom timestamps to your syslog output, it's perhaps best to use `syslog-ng`.

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065592/adding-year-in-the-syslog-message-linux/8620598#8620598) you could use `ts_format()` to specify the year in `syslog-ng`.

According to the `syslog-ng.conf(5)` man page:

> The syslog-ng application has a number of global options governing DNS
>   usage, the timestamp format used, and other general points. Each
>   option may have parameters, similarly to driver specifications. To set
>   global options, add an option statement to the syslog-ng configuration
>   file using the following syntax:
>
> `options { option1(params); option2(params); ... };`

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't include the year because the syslog format dates to the 1980s and programmers were less careful back then. Most log files were written for humans to read, not to be automatically parsed, and everybody knew what year it was.

Comment: Do you have a reference for that, with a more specific date than "the 1980s"?  (Section 5.1 of RFC3164 would be a good place to start.)  As it stands, this answer is quite vague and looks like a guess or opinion.

Comment: Well, I started using BSD 4.2 Unix in 1984. Syslog appeared in BSD 4.2  and that's when the decision was made to put in the month and day but not the year. (https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:1ZJoBFb9N7wJ:https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi%3Fquery%3Dsyslog%26sektion%3D3%26manpath%3Dfreebsd-release-ports+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-b-1)

Comment: See comment above about Mark Poltnick.